# How to display only the hours when minutes are zero with date formatter?

Tags: swift

Am currently using the format `MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm` to display the time stamp. Is it possible to drop the minutes if the time does not have any minute component ?

Like, instead of `3:00 PM` is it possible to display only `3 PM` ?

EDIT:

```
func formatDate(_ dateFormat: String, timeInterval: TimeInterval) -> String {
    let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: timeInterval)
    let formatter = DateFormatter()

    formatter.dateFormat = dateFormat
    return formatter.string(from: date) 
}

let formattedDate = formatDate("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm", timeInterval: 1520422200)
print(formattedDate)
```

Comment: Could you provide your code please

Comment: @Maximelc Err not sure why, but added.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Option 1**

Replace any with zero minutes on return string.

```
return formatter.string(from: date).replacingOccurrences(of: ":00", with: "")
```

**Option 2**

Determine if there are minutes, and adjust date format.

```
if (Int(timeInterval) % 3600 == 0) {
    let newFormat = dateFormat.replacingOccurrences(of: ":mm", with: "")

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I am using right now, but I thought there would be a straight forward way with `DateFormatter` ?

Comment: I don't think the DateFormatter includes any "smart" logic like that.

Comment: Bummer ! thats what I was afraid of.

Comment: Hey this works perfectly for me! Can't believe I didn't think of it before searching SO.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `DateComponents` to determine what the `.minute` component is. If it's non-zero set the date format to include minutes, and otherwise set it to leave it out.

Note if this is for a user-facing string, use [`setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter/1417087-setlocalizeddateformatfromtempla) and for hours use "j" so you can respect a user's setting for whether to display 24 hour time.

Note it is probably strange for most users to see 24 hour time without the minutes (e.g. "9pm" vs "21", the latter doesn't look right and probably would be better with ":00").